# How to sanitise string of Python code with Python?

Tags: python, security, jinja2

I am using Jinja2 as my templating engine for an admin dashboard, that displays some user feedback. I worry that an attacker could type some python code as their feedback and the Jinja2 template could execute that.

I.e.

An attacker might put the following as their feedback:

```
__import__('subprocess').getoutput('tree')
```

When the templater renders this, i.e.

```
feedback = "__import__('subprocess').getoutput('tree')"
Template("{{ feedback }}").render(feedback=feedback)
```

The tree command is run in the terminal.

How can I sanitise my strings so that they do not include any python code which might allow them access to my server via the command line?

Comment: Escape (or remove) `{` characters in the user-supplied string. Maybe jinja2 has some escape function to do it better.

Comment: I did not mean that the things between the {{}} brackets. Please read new edit.

Comment: I mean that the string contains the code, and is stored as a string variable. This is interpolated, and executed by the Jinja2 templater.

Comment: Your sample code is incorrect, it should be `feedback = '...'`. Then jinja2 won't run the tree command.

Comment: The template `{{ feedback }}` in your code is already safe and correct: Python commands within the feedback string variable won't be executed.

Comment: Unless you do `{{ feedback | safe }}`, your ... well, safe: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.safe

Comment: your example is wrong. When user put `self.__init__.__globals__.__builtins__...` as `feedback` in some `form` on page then it will treat it as normal string `"self.__init__.__globals__.__builtins__..."`, not Python code. And you get page with string `"self.__init__.__globals__.__builtins__..."`. You would have to use `exec()` or `eval()` to run it as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that the templater only executes it if you put it directly in the template.

So...

```
Template("{{ __import__('subprocess').getoutput('tree') }}").render()
```

executes the code.

Whereas...

```
x = "__import__('subprocess').getoutput('tree')"
Template("{{ x }}").render(x=x)
```

Will not. So treat them as strings and vulnerabilities are mitigated.